# Sudoku Solver - Scilab

Tags: algorithm, runtime-error, sudoku, backtracking, scilab

I wrote a program in SciLab that solves sudoku's.
But it can only solve sudoku's that always have a square with 1 possible value.
Like very easy and easy sudoku's on brainbashers.com .

Medium sudoku's always reach a point that they do not have a square with 1 possible value.
How can I modify my code to solve these, more difficult sudoku's?

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////   Check Sudoku   ///////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function r=OneToNine(V) // function checks if the given vector V contains 1 to 9
r = %T              // this works
u = %F
index = 1
while r == %T & index < 10
    for i=1 : length(V)
        if V(i)==index then 
            u = %T
        end
    end
    index=index+1
    if u == %F then r = %F
        else u = %F
    end          
end
if length(V) > 9 then r = %F
end
endfunction

function y=check(M) // Checks if the given matrix M is a solved sudoku
y = %T          // this works too

if size(M,1)<>9 | size(M,2)<>9 then // if it has more or less than 9 rows and columns
    y = %F                          // we return false
end

for i=1 : size(M,1)                 // if not all rows have 1-9 we return false
    if OneToNine(M(i,:)) == %F then
        y = %F
    end
end
endfunction


function P=PossibilitiesPosition(board, x, y)
// this one works
// we fill the vector possibilites with 9 zeros
// 0 means empty, 1 means it already has a value, so we don't need to change it

possibilities = []      // a vector that stores the possible values for position(x,y)
for t=1 : 9            // sudoku has 9 values
    possibilities(t)=0
end

// Check row f the value (x,y) for possibilities
// we fill the possibilities further by puttin '1' where the value is not possible 
for i=1 : 9            // sudoku has 9 values
    if board(x,i) > 0 then
        possibilities(board(x,i))=1
    end
end

// Check column of the value (x,y) for possibilities
// we fill the possibilities further by puttin '1' where the value is not possible
for j=1 : 9            // sudoku has 9 values
    if board(j, y) > 0 then
        possibilities(board(j, y))=1
    end
end

// Check the 3x3 matrix of the value (x,y) for possibilities
// first we see which 3x3 matrix we need
k=0
m=0
   if x >= 1 & x <=3 then
       k=1
   else if x >= 4 & x <= 6 then
           k = 4
   else k = 7
       end
   end
   if y >= 1 & y <=3 then
       m=1
   else if y >= 4 & y <= 6 then
           m = 4
   else m = 7
       end
   end

   // then we fill the possibilities further by puttin '1' where the value is not possible
   for i=k : k+2
       for j=m : m+2
           if board(i,j) > 0 then
               possibilities(board(i,j))=1
           end
       end           
   end       
   P = possibilities

   // we want to see the real values of the possibilities. not just 1 and 0
   for i=1 : 9            // sudoku has 9 values
       if P(i)==0 then
           P(i) = i
       else P(i) = 0
       end
   end

endfunction

function [x,y]=firstEmptyValue(board)           // Checks the first empty square of the sudoku    
R=%T                                        // and returns the position (x,y)
for i=1 : 9
    for j=1 : 9
        if board(i,j) == 0 & R = %T then
            x=i
            y=j
            R=%F
        end
    end
end
endfunction

function A=numberOfPossibilities(V)             // this checks the number of possible values for a position
A=0                                         // so basically it returns the number of elements different from 0 in the vector V
for i=1 : 9
    if V(i)>0 then
        A=A+1
    end
end
endfunction

function u=getUniquePossibility(M,x,y)          // this returns the first possible value for that square
pos = []                                    // in function fillInValue we only use it
pos = PossibilitiesPosition(M,x,y)          // when we know that this square (x,y) has only one possible value
for n=1 : 9
    if pos(n)>0 then
        u=pos(n)
    end
end
endfunction




///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////   Solve Sudoku   ///////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function G=fillInValue(M)               // fills in a square that has only 1 possibile value
x=0
y=0
pos = []

for i=1 : 9
        for j=1 : 9
            if M(i,j)==0 then
                if numberOfPossibilities(PossibilitiesPosition(M,i,j)) == 1 then
                    x=i
                    y=j
                    break
                end
            end
        end
        if x>0 then
            break
        end
    end
M(x,y)=getUniquePossibility(M,x,y)
G=M
endfunction

function H=solve(M)                     // repeats the fillInValue until it is a fully solved sudoku
P=[]
P=M
if check(M)=%F then
   P=fillInValue(M)
   H=solve(P)        
else
    H=M
end
endfunction


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

So it solves this first one

```
// Very easy and easy sudokus from brainbashers.com get solved completely
// Very Easy sudoku from brainbashers.com

M = [0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 0
     7 0 4 0 0 0 8 0 2
     0 5 8 4 0 7 1 3 0
     0 0 1 2 8 4 9 0 0
     0 0 0 7 0 5 0 0 0
     0 0 7 9 3 6 5 0 0
     0 8 9 5 0 2 4 6 0
     4 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 9
     0 1 0 0 0 0 0 8 0]
```

But it doens't solve this medium:

```
M2= [0 0 6 8 7 1 2 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     5 0 1 3 0 9 7 0 8
     1 0 7 0 0 0 6 0 9
     2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7
     9 0 3 0 0 0 8 0 1
     3 0 5 9 0 7 4 0 2
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 2 4 3 5 1 0 0]
```

Error code when trying to solve medium sudoku:

```
-->solve(M2)
 !--error 21 
Invalid index.
at line      14 of function PossibilitiesPosition called by :  
at line       3 of function getUniquePossibility called by :  
at line      20 of function fillInValue called by :  
at line     182 of function solve called by :  
at line     183 of function solve called by :  
at line     183 of function solve called by :  
at line     183 of function solve called by :  
at line     183 of function solve called by :  
solve(M2)
at line     208 of exec file called by :    
_SCILAB-6548660277741359031.sce', 1
while executing a callback
```

Comment: General approach: In case there are multiple possibilities, choose one and try to solve the remaining version. If this does not work out, choose the next option etc.

Comment: You wrote a function firstEmptyValue but you are not using it; you still have the old double loop  within fillInValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one of the easiest way to program a Sudoku solver (not the most efficient) could be to solve each cell with all the possible options recursively (which could be similar to the "Backtracking" algorithm) until a full answer is found.

Another options (I would say it's better) is to iterate trough all the squares solving all the "simple" squares and storing the possible answers in the others squares, then repeat (now you have some more solved), repeat the process until the Sudoku is solved or no more squares can be solved directly. Then you could try the rest with brute-force or Backtracking (maybe half or more of the Sudoku is already solved, so it may be relatively efficient)

Anyway,with a quick search I found [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms) where some Sudoku solving algorithms are explained with pseudo-code examples, hopefully these will be useful to you